# Get the CCNetBuildDate in NAnt parallel tasks

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, nant, cruisecontrol, ccnet-config

In a cruise control configuration file, I use a set of parallel tasks to call some NAnt targets. I noticed that the CC system parameters (like CCNetBuildDate) are not pushed to the NAnt scripts, while they are pushed when I remove the parallel flag. How can I push the CCNetBuildDate information to my parallel tasks?

Comment: Sounds like problem with how parallel was implemented. What parallel NAnt tasks are you talking about? The ones from CIFactory? If yes, then unfortunately that code is long dead.

Comment: I am using the <parallel> tasks in the CruiseControl configuration files, that call a set of <nant> targets.

Comment: My mistake, didn't know such functionality existed: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parallel_Task Could you please log a bug with CruiseControl.Net then? That's clearly a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I opened the following bug in CruiseControl.NET:
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/issues/201

Answer (score 1):

When I tested this (1.5) I got *0001-01-01* for *CCNetBuildDate*.

Until this bug is fixed you could save the correct settings before executing the parallel tasks. As you can not override properties passed on the command line you would have to change their names or use `<exec>` to call nant directly:

```
    <nant>
        <buildFile>SaveCCNetParameters.build</buildFile>
     </nant>
     <parallel>
       <tasks>
         <exec>
            <executable>$(NAntExePath)</executable>
            <buildArgs>-buildfile:Build1.build @CCNetBuildParameters</buildArgs>
         </exec>
         <exec>
            <executable>$(NAntExePath)</executable>
            <buildArgs>-buildfile:Build2.build @CCNetBuildParameters</buildArgs>
         </exec>
       </tasks>
     </parallel>
```

where *CCNetBuildParameters* is a file looking similar to:

```
-DCCNetBuildDate=2012-11-10
-DCCNetBuildTime=12:12:12
-DCCNetLabel=123
[...]
```